# How to trigger with Snap Svg?

Tags: jquery, svg

It seems trigger event doesn't work with [snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) ?

Basicly what I want is  trigger a `click` event, but it seems not working with [snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) or I am doing something wrong.

I could not solve it.

So how to do it?

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/p0mrc2uv/1)

```js
var s=Snap("#svg");
var rect=s.rect(0, 0, 100,600)
rect.attr({ 
fill:"#212121"
});

var animating = true;

function aniOn() {
  if (animating) {
    rect.animate({
      width: 400
    }, 1000, mina.elastic);
  };
}

function aniOff() {
  if (animating) {
    rect.animate({
      width: 100
    }, 1000, mina.elastic);
  };
}
rect.click(function() {
  animating = true;
  aniOn()
});

rect.mouseout(function() {
  animating = true;
  aniOff()
});
$("#button").click(function() {
  rect.trigger('click');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#svg {
  position:absolute;
}

#button {
  margin-left:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<svg id="svg"  width="200" height="100%" >
</svg>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rect` is not recognized by jQuery as an element, you should use a selector to pick it, like `$('rect')` or if you want to be more specific `$('#svg rect')`, and you need to do this in both the `.click()` function as well as the `.trigger()`, so it'll be something like this:

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p0mrc2uv/3/)

```js
var s=Snap("#svg");
var rect=s.rect(0, 0, 100,600)
rect.attr({ 
fill:"#212121"
});

var animating = true;


function aniOn() {
  if (animating) {
    rect.animate({
      width: 400
    }, 1000, mina.elastic);
  };
}



function aniOff() {
  if (animating) {
    rect.animate({
      width: 100
    }, 1000, mina.elastic);
  };
}
$('rect').click(function() {
  animating = true;
  aniOn();
  console.log('clicked!') // I've added this for demonstration purpose
});

rect.mouseout(function() {
  animating = true;
  aniOff()
});


$("#button").click(function() {
  $('rect').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#svg { position:absolute; }
#button { margin-left:200px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg"  width="200" height="100%" ></svg>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: but it was working , i mean " rect.click(function) " ?

Comment: it was working as *pure* javascript `.click` not as jQuery object, if you want a proof, change this `rect.click(function()` to `rect.on('click', function()` which is jQuery and you'll get an error "**`Uncaught TypeError: rect.on is not a function`**", but if you write it like `$('rect').on('click', function()` you will *not* get that error and it;'ll work just fine